# multi image in canvas order manage by drag and droppable list in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, fabricjs

I tried to implement Photoshop like layer management using fabricjs
in angular. Which library is most suitable this any suggestion. I attach my plan below

[my plan is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBTYd.jpg)

Comment: you can try konva js

Comment: Tnx.Yes main issue is it's not maintaining angular library

Comment: you can install the package from npm and use in the angular app